# Excel file (.xlsx) created by saving byte stream in C# cannot be opened

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am attempting to save an Excel (.xlsx) file in disk that is sent to a webservice. The code I have used is as follows, However when I click on the saved file it returns a "The File is corrupt and cannot be opened" error. But the same methodology works for CSV files.

```
  string dataFile = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataFile);
  MemoryStream stream_ = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
  MultipartParser.MultipartParser mp = new MultipartParser.MultipartParser(stream_);

  // Save Excel file
  File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\output.xlsx", mp.FileContents);
```

Comment: Have you tried disposing the stream_?

Comment: Is your data in xlsx format? I don't think so.

Comment: yes it is in xlsx format

Comment: @DafaDil: You're writing same data in *.csv file. How that is possible?

Comment: @Ali Sepehri.Kh sorry it was just to show I removed it now

Comment: don't use `ReadAsStringAsync` its a binary file! csv are text files and can be safely read that way.

Comment: @Daniel A White  what abt Request.Content.ReadAsAsync()?

Comment: If you are trying to retrieve an uploaded file you probably want something like `var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);`

Comment: how can I get the file contents from the provide (preferably as  byte array or stream)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked,

```
        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            string fileName = "";
            string fileLocalName = "";
            var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                fileLocalName = file.LocalFileName;
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\output.xlsx", File.ReadAllBytes(fileLocalName));
        }
```

Thanks for the help, Ben Robinson, Daniel A. White, Ali Sepehri.Kh and Faisal Hafeez for the help